# Sleep operation in C++ on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, sleep

I want to perform the above mentioned operation in milliseconds as the unit. Which library and function call should I prefer?

Comment: nanosleep(), usleep() might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

EDIT 2017: C++11 `sleep_for` is the right way to do this. Please see [Xornad's answer, below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19446811/751061).

---

C++03:

Since Mac OS X is Unix-based, you can almost always just use the standard linux functions!

In this case you can use `usleep` (which takes a time in microseconds) and just multiply your milliseconds by 1000 to get microseconds.

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main () {
    usleep(1000); // will sleep for 1 ms
    usleep(1); // will sleep for 0.001 ms
    usleep(1000000); // will sleep for 1 s
}
```

For more info on this function, check out the Linux man page:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep

Comment: If you are compiling on OS 10.7 or above, see Xornand's answer below! Using C++11 is far more cross-platform than using OS-specific code!

Comment: to use C++11 functionality, you have to turn it on specifically in Xcode. See my comment below on @Xornand's answer!

Comment: sleep(0.001f) will sleep for 0 seconds (sleep takes an int)

Comment: Better use nanosleep(), usleep() is deprecated (in POSIX).

Answer (score 16):

If you have C++11 support in your compiler, you can use the `sleep_for` and avoid having to use an OS specific API. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: c++11 support is available to me in xcode 4.6.3 but the header thread is not present ?

Comment: This is a far better answer than mine! (Thanks Xornand, I've never thought to use these!)

Comment: But you're right, to get C++11 headers to compile in Xcode, you need to turn on the C++11 library support. Go to your project in the navigator, click on Build Settings and then search for C++ Standard Library. Change the setting for your project to `libc++`.
I have edited Xornand's excellent answer to reflect this information, but it won't be visible until my edits are accepted. :)

Comment: @m_j please change the accepted answer to this one! :)

Answer (score 0):

please just use sleep(integer or number) unless you need nanoseconds or microseconds

Comment: Questioner indicates he needs a resolution of milliseconds; `sleep()` provides a resolution of seconds.